# How is this question about general computing hardware and software?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This question [Cannot delete a file even when logged in as an Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25798272/3416774) is closed as "about general computing hardware and software". But how is it exactly so? According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it should be opened as it's about "software tools commonly used by programmers", no?

Comment: "Tools commonly used by programmers" is not "catch them all category". Just because programmers use some tool, does not automatically make any question involving the tool on topic here. One liner for deleting a file in command line is definitely not a programming problem.

Comment: The accepted answer consists in adding options to the command line. Maybe not a programming question, but at least a programming solution ...

Comment: Because the issue is very obviously operating system account permissions, which is not a programming problem.

Comment: @IanKemp "obviously" is very subjective, do you think so?

Comment: @Ooker in this case, absolutely not. Using a search engine for the phrase in question will turn up sites telling you how to fix the problem within the operating system. They may or may not tell you how to fix that problem using programming tools, but the programming tools are not central to the problem in any way shape or form.

Comment: PowerShell (and command lines in general) are used by power usesrs. Not specifically by programmers. There is some overlap between these two groups but they are not one and the same. I've used command line to do various tasks for *years* before writing my first line of code. System administrators also commonly use command line and various command line tools without being programmers.

Comment: @VLAZ TIL command line ≠ programming. From Wikipedia, [scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language "Scripting language - Wikipedia") is a programming language, hence isn't that using it is also programming?

Comment: If you type in `ping 192.168.0.1` does that count as programming? Because I do not think so. It's invoking an application. It's just a CLI one rather than clicking on some GUI.

Comment: @Ooker Yes, *programming* in a scripting language is *programming*. However, just using a command line to enter commands is *not* inherently programming.

Comment: @Makyen I see. Should this information be mentioned in the help page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't about operating systems, it's about programming. And that question is **not** about a programming error, but about an error produced by an OS. The fact that the asker is using PowerShell is irrelevant - they would have had the same or similar error if they'd attempted to manually perform the same action via the OS.

Therefore, that question is far more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Unfortunately, the text "software tools commonly used by programmers" is yet another example of how the so-called Help Centre is almost entirely useless at informing people of what is actually expected of them while using this site. "software tools commonly used by programmers" is a term so broad as to be meaningless, that can easily (and I'd argue correctly) be interpreted to include OSes, except the reality is that said interpretation is incorrect for this site.

There have been numerous requests over many years to improve the wording in the Help Centre, but Stack Exchange Inc. doesn't care enough to fix it, just like they don't care enough to fix anything else that needs to be fixed here.

Comment: isn't that the help page can be modified by community mods?

Comment: Nope. Moderators have way less power than you'd imagine.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong here. We can edit help center pages. The last edit was made 6 days ago by a mod

Comment: I routinely use a pen, as I am sure do most programmers, so here come all of my pen questions relating to the chemical make-up of ink...

Answer (score 2):

That question isn't even remotely unique to software development - you could easily see a power user wanting to do the exact same thing (unless you think that only programmers delete files).

The mere fact that you encountered a problem while programming doesn't automatically make it on-topic. For example, awhile back I ran into a problem with my Chrome settings while programming; it wasn't really unique to software development (Chrome is widely used by non-programmers, and the particular task would've been of interest to power users too), so I ended up posting it on Super User, where it was well-received.

In terms of the relevant portion of the on-topic guide, note the next bullet point: it must be a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". This problem is practical and answerable, but it's not unique to software development.

Answer (score 0):

It's a grey area, in my experience. Sometimes you'll see a question like this closed, sometimes you'll see it answered. Sometimes it'll be downvoted, sometimes it'll be upvoted. It all depends on who reviews the question at that moment in time and how they interpret the "tools commonly used by programmers" rule, if they do at all.

What muddies the waters is the modern concept of dev/ops. Nowadays you see developers having to do much more than programming related tasks including setting up entire server environments, configuring networks, managing cloud services, setup monitoring, etc. etc. But that does not change the target of Stack Overflow; it is not to 100% service the needs of programmers, it is to be a repository of knowledge specifically for programming problems. Not for programmer's problems - *programming* problems. Written almost the same but with a vastly different scope.

That remains the, by design, restricted scope of this specific site. For other types of questions that service the further needs of programmers there are other sites available.