# Why does this meta question about a specific closed question in the main get downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, downvote-reason

The meta question [How is this question about general computing hardware and software?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418644/3416774) is heavily downvoted. Now after a long time using the network I finally find my peace when my post is downvoted, so I don't feel hurt with that. However, I still want to understand why it is downvoted. Is it because the voters think that I'm suggesting OS question should be on-topic too?

Comparing to [this similar example question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289838/3416774), can you tell me the differences between them?

Comment: 2015 was a different time; far more people are active on meta than there were 7 years ago. The question from 7 years ago has been viewed just **2** more times than the other.

Comment: (Now the newer question has *more* views.)

Comment: I'm going to second the notion of the initial issue being [obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418644/how-is-this-question-about-general-computing-hardware-and-software#comment914598_418644), which kind of makes *this* issue obvious as well, doesn't it? The initial question didn't make much of an effort to show why the voting wasn't adequate (or not obvious) and this one doesn't either. The "similar" meta-question's topic is far away and much more borderline than yours.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Since I answered your counterexample](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289852/1079354), I'll bite.

There are two big differences that I can see.

- The older question asks *if* this question is on-topic or should be closed.  The newer question asks *why* this question is closed.
- The older question references a question about nomenclature or terminology, a subject which is a bit of a gray area in parts and has had a spotty history of moderation.  The newer question explicitly references some problem with a user's account, which is outside of the scope of programming altogether.

To the first difference, the question "should this be closed" tends to invite more conversation than "why is this closed", and tends to inspire less ire.  *Usually*, "why is this closed"-shaped questions tend to be an OP ranting about our moderation prowess and how they disagree with what we've done.  That's normally off-putting to us as a means of discussion, so a visceral reaction to that is to downvote the meta question.

To the second difference, in the first example there's a lot less certainty about the topicality, so there's a lot more opportunity for differing perspectives to agree or disagree on the merits of *the main site's question*.  In the second example, it's a **lot more explicit** that this isn't a problem that is solved by writing PowerShell, so this invites *less* discussion about the main site's question.

Answer (score 4):

As [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/3750257) says,

> On posts tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change in addition to usual reasons based on the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

In practice, people sometimes extend this principle to other kinds of meta questions and vote on posts complaining about specific actions on main based on their opinions on the action being challenged (that is, downvote your Meta post because they feel the question was correctly closed and thus ranting about it on Meta is counterproductive)

Comment: Thank you for that reminder. Over the years I have basically given up. People simply shortcut on meta and vote on the question instead writing answers and voting on them. That's all.

Comment: @Trilarion oi, not all of us are that lazy :( I try to answer when I can to coax out the tally, I just did so an hour or so ago. I'll even do it when I am almost sure I have the unpopular opinion, because I believe in the value of having it in fine print what people do *not* want. It kind of depends on how important people find the issue brought up in the meta post before you see any real useful voting on answers though, it is a bit of a shame.

Answer (score 3):

The first Meta question you link to is stating that the linked question is not about general computing, which I disagree with. Votes on Meta posts that ask for something specific to happen indicate agreement or disagreement, and I don't agree with that post.